# Retornar apenas os valores positivos de uma array

Tags: javascript

Pede pra que eu faça uma função, que recebe um parâmetro (`array`) e retorne os saldos positivos (***com lucro***) desse Mês, utilizando `for` e provavelmente um `if`.

**Exemplo:**

```
saldosDeMesesComLucro([100, 20, 0, -10, 10]);
```

**Saída**

```
// deve retornar [100, 20, 10].
```

**Tentei:**

```js
function saldoDeMesesComLucro(saldos){
  for(var i = 0; i < saldos.length; i++){
    if(saldos[i] > 0){
     return saldos;
    }
  }
}
```

Mas não é a lógica correta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu código, ao encontrar um saldo positivo a função é interrompida e todo o array é retornado, sem nenhuma mudança.

No código a seguir, os valores positivos são inseridos em um novo array, e após percorrer todos os valores do array original, o novo array é retornado.

```
function saldoDeMesesComLucro(saldos){
  saldosPositivos = [];

  for(var i = 0; i < saldos.length; i++){
    if(saldos[i] > 0){
     saldosPositivos.push( saldos[i] );
    }
  }

  return saldosPositivos;
}
```

Comment: Pode tambem usar o `map` para retornar um novo array da forma que deseja  
`const valoresPositivos = saldos.map(item => item > 0)`

Comment: Sim, mas eu achei essa forma mais simples pra quem aparentemente não tem muita experiência.

Answer (score 2):

você consegue o mesmo resultado usando o `filter`, dessa forma:

```js
let saldoPositivo = [100, 20, 0, -10, 10].filter(saldo=> saldo>0)

console.log(saldoPositivo)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Mas não é a lógica correta?

Não a sua lógica está errada porque no momento que ele encontrar o saldo de um determinada posição o código vai retornar tudo novamente e deve guardar o valor da pesquisa em alguma variável para depois retornar somente o valores que foram satisfeito na comparação.

Como deveria ser o código, exemplo:

```js
const saldos = [100,-1,-2,-9,50,10,-8];

function retornarSaldosPositivos(saldos) {
  let sp = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < saldos.length; i++){
    if (saldos[i] > 0) {
      sp.push(saldos[i]);
    }
  }
  return sp;
}

console.log(retornarSaldosPositivos(saldos));
```

Ou de uma maneira simplificada com um filtro:

```js
const saldos = [100,-1,-2,-9,50,10,-8];

const saldosPositivos = saldos.filter(function(s){
  return s > 0;
}, saldos);

console.log(saldosPositivos);
```